# Sub querying data over a SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I've the following query,
Query the Western Longitude (LONG_W) for the largest Northern Latitude (LAT_N) in STATION that is less than 137.2345
137.2345. Round your answer to 4 decimal places.
The schema for the table STATION is id, city, state, lat_N, long_w

This is my code,

```
SELECT LONG_W 
FROM STATION 
WHERE LAT_N IN
(SELECT ROUND(MAX(LAT_N), 4) FROM STATION WHERE LAT_N < 137.2345);
```

This doesn't work, what am I doing wrong here.

Comment: Sounds like you need to round `LONG_W`, not the column in your WHERE clause.

Comment: You are comparing LAT_N which is rounded to 4 decimal places with the actual value of LAT_N from database. What exactly do you want to round? LONG_W?

Comment: Yup worked finally, I was rounding off the wrong value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's several things wrong here.

For one thing, there is no guarantee that value in LAT_N is going to be equal to ROUND(LAT_N,4).

```
 78.123456 = ROUND(78.123456,4)   --> FALSE
```

I don't see any need for a subquery.

Maximum value for a latitude (in degrees) is going to be 90. I think the question was asking for values of LONG_W that were less than 137.2345

I read the question as specifying...

- access the rows in the station table
- exclude rows that don't satisfy LONG_W < 137.2345
- from those rows, find the "largest" value LAT_N
- round that largest value of LAT_N to 4 decimal places
- return the rounded value

---

I'd write the query like this:

```
 SELECT ROUND(MAX(s.lat_n),4) AS largest_lat_n
    FROM station s
   WHERE s.long_w < 137.2345
```

Maybe I'm reading the question wrong. (This isn't a SQL problem, it's a specification problem.)

If the question is instead asking...

- access the rows in the station table
- exclude rows that don't satisfy LONG_W < 137.2345
- from those rows, find the row with the "largest" value LAT_N
- take the LONG_W from that row with largest LAT_N
- round that LONG_W to 4 decimal places
- return the rounded value

To get *other* values on the row that have the largest LAT_N, I could do something like this:

```
  SELECT ROUND(s.long_w,4)
    FROM station s
   WHERE s.long_w < 137.2345
   ORDER BY s.lat_n DESC
   LIMIT 1
```

If I want to use a subquery, there's a potential that we'll get multiple rows back with the same LAT_N, and some of those values of LONG_W could be larger than 137.2345

Consider a table containing rows with values:

```
LAT_N     LONG_W
-------   ---------
87.654321 131.313131
87.654321 140.404040
```

... and assume that the value of 87.654321 is the "largest" that occurs for rows with LONG_W < 137.2345. (That is, no other rows with a larger LAT_N.)

Consider the return from this statement:

```
 SELECT t.long_w
   FROM ( SELECT MAX(s.lat_n) AS largest_lat_n
            FROM station s
           WHERE s.long_w < 137.2345
        ) s
   JOIN station t
     ON t.lat_n = s.largest_lat_n
```

That's going to return *both* of the rows. If we do a MAX() function, we're going to get back the higher value, 140.4040404 value. And that doesn't seem to match the specification.  To prevent larger values of LONG_W from being returned, we'd either need to add a predicate to the query (condition in the WHERE clause)

```
  WHERE t.long_w < 137.2345
```

Or, we could use an expression in the SELECT list to filter out LONG_W values that don't meet the specification

```
 SELECT MAX( IF(t.long_w<137.2345,t.long_w,NULL) ) AS long_w
```

Comment: I may have misread the specification. I've added another interpretation of the specification, and the approaches I would take to returning that result.

Comment: I think the specification is awkwardly worded. I typically identify the table(s) to be queried e.g. "query the station table", and identify the  expressions to be returned e.g. "return the western longitude". My first cut may have been a misinterpretation of the spec. BEWARE: if you use a subquery or inline view to get the largest LAT_N from the set of rows with LONG_W < 137, when you go back to the table to get rows that have a matching LAT_N.... that doesn't prevent returning rows with a matching LAT_N and LONG_W *larger* than 137. (The SQL we write depends on the specification.)

Comment: I think, judging by all the low quality answers this poor questions attracts, that "the specification" is a homework assignment. Teacher needs to change up their questions after 5 years.

Answer (score 2):

You should `ROUND` the value retrieved like this:

```
Select ROUND(LONG_W,4) 
from STATION 
where LAT_N = (
    Select max(LAT_N) 
    from STATION where 
    LAT_N < 137.2345
);
```

Comment: Can you please explain your answer so others can understand why it is supposed to work and learn from it. 
You can also use markdown to format your answer,
which is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It is much simple and works fine.

```
SELECT ROUND(LONG_W,4) 
FROM STATION 
WHERE LAT_N < 137.2345 
ORDER BY LAT_N DESC LIMIT 1;
```